# Error dual boot ubuntu, not show grub selection

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I installed ubuntu 20.4 next to windows 10, uefi mode, but when i start the computer starts directly ubuntu, i can't select windows 10.
I tried with boot-repair and i get: LegacyWindows detectado. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB).

In ubuntu in sys/firmware i have efi folder, and the computer came with gpt whit windows 10 installed.

I installed both windows and ubuntu on ssd m2 nvme disk

Comment: anyone knows what is the problem? or what can i do

Comment: Setting in UEFI is for installed systems. How you boot USB flash drive depends on your choice each time you boot. UEFI should give you two choices one UEFI:XXX and one XXX where XXX is name or label of flash drive. But some tools that create USB flash drive may make it only UEFI or only BIOS. Make sure it is UEFI/gpt not BIOS/CSM/Legacy on MBR.

Comment: i leave you an image of rufus in the next comment of how i burned the usb, when i'am installing ubuntu, doesn't say 'install ubuntu with windows' it only show install ubuntu in all disk or more options, so it does not recognize windows, and when i restart windows with shift press, it only have power off and uefi firmare options, no usb to run

Comment: You have to have fast startup off in Windows as that sets hibernation flag on all Windows partitions. And Linux driver will not normal mount partitions with hibernation flag to prevent damage. Make sure fast startup is off. Note Windows keeps turning it on with most updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: i have fast startup off in windows and i tried disabling it in uefi, and as it says in the link, i have disabled hibernation too

Comment: if it is important, the installation of windows i have now, its a clone of and hdd to ssd, but it works fine

Comment: Clone should be ok, as long as you do not have both drives still connected. Clones duplicate UUIDs/GUIDs and duplicates not allowed when booting.

Comment: what can i do ?

Comment: For whatever reason we see users who try a different install tool, different flash drive and/or a different USB port and then it works. Do not know if technical issue or just redoing it made it correctly. Most find this works:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb or 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb
Lots of info on USB boot for installing
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: i just did that things, burn another usb device with win32diskimager in another usb port and no recognize windows 10, i tried with uefi witi csm and nothing works

Comment: i also tried with linux mint too, and have the same problem

Comment: If you have UEFI system and Windows in UEFI mode, never turn on legacy/BIOS/CSM mode, you are wasting time and may create more problems. And always create UEFI bootable installers and boot in UEFI mode as choice in UEFI boot menu.Windows fast start up must be off. See above. Did you update UEFI, & SSD firmware? And change drive to AHCI? But install AHCI driver into Windows?

Comment: I updated the image. because in a post i saw that there apears windows 10, but i don't see any os, is that important?, in other hand, i tried to update bios (i think that is uefi) but i had an error so i couldn't, and ssd firmware and AHCI driver i dont  know what is, how to do that?

Comment: oh, yes in bios in SATA configuratios i have enabled AHCI, and intel rs premium disabled. I tried to update the AHCI drivers in windows and i have the latest version

Comment: and i see that i have updated the ssd firmware

Comment: If you have AHCI on and Windows fast start up off, installer should see Windows, but still better to use Something Else, so you can control partition size and if you want optional /home partition. Otherwise auto install just uses all the unallocated space for / (root).

Comment: installer still doesn't see windows

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
May or may not show something. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: sorry, i couldn't understand, i have to follow the instructions in the link on the usb installer?

Comment: You say you have it installed already in question, so the Boot-Repair report run from live installer in live mode, will show if that is the case and maybe what issue is. If still installer issues, not sure what issue then is.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Lots of info on USB boot for installing
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb